# SharePoint Lists.asmx throwing "Object moved to here" error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, web-services

We have a scheduled asp.net EXE application that uses the Lists.asmx web service from SharePoint 2010, compares lists items against a database table (based on a key) and updates all matches back to the SharePoint list. This was working fine for a few days and then it started to fail intermittently with the following error:

> Object moved to here.

It doesn't fail consistently. It fails most times but it also succeeds some times. Whenever it fails, it updates about 2/3 of the list items and then fails. I can't reproduce this when I run the program from Visual Studio in debug mode.

Any suggestions on why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to trace the web service call with Fiddler to find more detailed information. And make sure the lists service url is valid and valid user credential passed to the web service when calling it.
And this error could happen when configuring mixed authentication in SharePoint, reference here:

[The request failed with the error message: Object moved (SharePoint 2010, Web Services & FBA)](https://sharepointyankee.com/2011/01/04/the-request-failed-with-the-error-message-object-moved-sharepoint-2010-web-services-fba/)